# How to access original image after applying filter on image using ALAsset library ?

Tags: ios, iphone, alassetslibrary, alasset

I have applied filter to an image in iPhone after then when i export that image in mac it provide me the original not the filter one. If i access this image using ALAsset library framework it provides me the filtered image but i want to access both images filtered and original image using ALAsset library . So how can i do this

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't bother: The Assets Library framework is deprecated as of iOS 9.0.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that assets library framework is deprecated. But still i want to access these images .Anyways can you give me any idea how can i fetch these images using Photos Framework .